# Find the equation of a plane tangent to a given surface at given point.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of a plane tangent to a given surface at given point.
$x^3+y^3+z^3-36=0$ $    P=(2,1,3)$

Am I doing in a good way?

$ \nabla= [3x^2;3y^2;3z^2] $ 
$ \nabla (P0)= [12;3;27] $

following the equation

$ 12(x-2)+3(y-1)-27(z-3)=0$

$ 12x+3y-27z=-54 $

Is it my plane?

Comment: Why is there a minus sign in front of $27$?

Comment: I followed the equation $fx(P0)(x-x0)+fy(P0)(y-y0)-fz(P0)(z-z0)=0$ ?
@DavidQuinn

Comment: That equation that you’re mechanically plugging values into corresponds to a gradient of $[f_x,f_y,-1]$ (which you’d get from an equation of the form $z=f(x,y)$), but that’s not what you have.

Comment: Should it be $fx(P0)(x-x0)+fy(P0)(y-y0)+fz(P0)(z-z0)=0$ ?
and in equation +27(z-3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal to the plane is $\nabla f$ Which you have calculated as $(12,3,27)$ or $(4,1,9)$

So the equation of the plane is $$\underline{r}\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}4\\1\\9\end {matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}2\\1\\3\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}4\\1\\9\end {matrix}\right)$$

So $$4x+y+9z=36$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall Taylor series (expansion of first order at a  point coinides with a plane tangent to the surface at this point)

$$f(x,y,z)\approx f(x_0,y_0,z_0)+\vec{\mathrm{grad}}(f)(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot\left[(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)\right] \tag{*}$$
Therefore $(*)$ equated to $0$ is the equation for that plane:
$$f(x_0,y_0,z_0)+\vec{\mathrm{grad}}(f)(x_0,y_0,z_0)\cdot\left[(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)\right]=0$$